# Is it possible to fetch data from the database server-side while using useFormStatus client-side in Next.js using the App Router?

Tags: next.js, app-router, next.js14

I'm trying to create an **edit-form** for editing user data (name, email and password).

And I want to **pre-fill** the input fields with the current user data (name and email).

But because `useFormStatus`'s `pending` property is a client-component feature, I can't use Next.js **Server Actions** to fetch data from the database (or at least I couldn't figure out how to do that). Instead I fetch the data from a client component using **SWR** or the `fetch()` function.

**My question is**: "Is my only option fetching the user data from the database from the client's side or is there a way to fetch the data on the server side and filling the html input fields on the server-side?"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I've split the single client component into two components, the server component passes down the current user data via parameters to the client component.